# How to make Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject immutable?

Tags: c#, json.net

I can create JObject

```
var jobject = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(jsonstring);
```

I want to convert the jobject read only so that no new keys can be added or existing values modified.

Comment: What is the scope of `jobject`? Would [C# public variable as writeable inside the class but readonly outside the class](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4662190/1115360) be of use to you?

Comment: @AndrewMorton I do not control the JObject class. I can write a wrapper around it but it will not be trivial.

Comment: You don't need to alter the JObject class, rather, just control the access to that `jobject` instance. Or are you saying that *all* instances of JObject must be read-only?

Comment: @AndrewMorton not all but I do not understand how to control access without writing a wrapper class.

Comment: You can throw an exception in [`JObject.PropertyChanging`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/E_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_PropertyChanging.htm) and [`JContainer.ListChanged`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/E_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JContainer_ListChanged.htm), but the latter happens *after* the change, so it's too late.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can't be done. There is an open issue for implementing it:

https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/468

But it is two years old and has drawn very little attention as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 2):

An immutable object is one that can't be changed. If you don't want consumers of your JObject to change it, just give them a copy. (Note: this example uses the abstract superclass `JToken` of `JObject` to provide a more general solution.)

```
private JToken data = JToken.Parse(@"{""Some"":""JSON""}");

public JToken Data()
{
   return data.DeepClone();
}

public JToken Data(string path)
{
   return data.SelectToken(path).DeepClone();
}
```

The consumer will be able to change their copy, but not the source.

If `data` is so large that cloning it is prohibitive, use the second method `JToken Data(string path)` to grab a subset.