# Access a class property only from a certain class

Tags: vb.net

Suppose I have the following class:

```
Public Class lbMenu

    Inherits Form

    ...

    Public Sub AddItem(header As String)
        Dim item As New lbMenuItem()
        item.Owner = Me
        item.Header = header
        Controls.Add(item)
    End Sub

    ...

End Class
```

and also the following class:

```
Public Class lbMenuItem

    Inherits Control

    Private _Owner As lbMenu
    Public Property Owner As lbMenu
        Get
            Return _Owner
        End Get
        Set(value As lbMenu)
            _Owner = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _Header As String
    Public Property Header As String
        Get
            Return _Header
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _Header = value
        End Set
    End Property

    ...

End Class
```

As you can see, I access the `Owner` property of `lbMenuItem` from the class `lbMenu`.

What I want is that nobody else can access the `Owner` property, or maybe just to read the value of the property. I think there is no way to do that but maybe there is a solution to reach a similar situation.

Any suggestions?

---

**Edit:**

I already considered passing the owner as a parameter in the constructor, but I want that anyone can access the `lbMenuItem` class. Anyone can create a new instance of the class, read and write many properties, etc. The only thing I don't want is that someone can **write** the `Owner` property. Someone can create a new instance of the class without having to pass an `ownerMenu` parameter to the `New` method (he can't know what `ownerMenu` is for). For the same reason, `lbMenuItem` can't be a nested class of `lbMenu`.
I'm trying to get the same result as with `ContextMenuStrip` and `ToolStripMenuItem`. `ToolStripMenuItem` has an `Owner` property (which in this case has read/write access) and an `OwnerItem` which is read-only.
So, is there a way to make the `Owner` property read-only but writable from the `lbMenu` class?

Comment: It could be part of the New while having the property readonly. If the write part of the property could be friend, depends on the need.

Comment: You can protect that property with the [Friend](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/declared-elements/access-levels) keyword but it is not clear if this is enough. It depends on how you have structured your program

Comment: Does `lbMenu` need to access `lbMenuItem.Owner` after an instance of `lbMenuItem` is created?

Comment: Yes, in some cases lbMenu needs to access the lbMenuItem.Owner property.

Comment: I just edited my answer to address the new points you added.

Comment: Just curious why you need such level of protection? If I am developer and having access to the class, and feel that I need to set `Owner` I will create setter for that even you spend time for defensing against it. Having constructor and readonly property will be tell me that owner should be set only through constructor.

Comment: I can't believe!!! I always misundertood the meaning of the keyword `Friend`! (well, I never coded a dll before). That's exactly what I **need**. Thank you all very much!

Answer (score 0):

You could just have the `Owner` property private *or read-only if you want to allow reading its value* and set it in the constructor.

**Edit:**

> Someone can create a new instance of the class without having to pass
>   an `ownerMenu` parameter to the `New` method

Well, you can have two constructors, one that accepts a `lbMenu` parameter, and one without. So, your code would look something like this:

```
Public Class lbMenu

    Public Sub AddItem(header As String)
        Dim item As New lbMenuItem(Me)
        item.Header = header
        Controls.Add(item)
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class lbMenuItem

    ' Use this instead if you don't want the property to be accessible at all.
    'Private Property Owner As lbMenu

    Public ReadOnly Property Owner As lbMenu
    Public Property Header As String

    ' Allow creating an instance of the class without having to pass/set the owner.
    Public Sub New()
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ownerMenu As lbMenu)
        Owner = ownerMenu
    End Sub

End Class
```

**One last recommendation:**

Based on the names of your classes, you might consider having a parent/child relationship between them (i.e., the `lbMenuItem` class would be a nested class within `lbMenu`). This will give you the advantage of being able to access the private members of `lbMenu` from a `lbMenuItem` instance.

Hope that helps.

---

### Addressing the new points in your edit:

> `ToolStripMenuItem` has an `Owner` property ... and an `OwnerItem` which is read-only.

That's exactly what I proposed (i.e., to use a read-only property). Note that the `OwnerItem` property isn't exposed as *writable* to any other class.

> So, is there a way to make the `Owner` property read-only but writable
>   from the `lbMenu` class?

No, that's not possible. A read-only property is read-only, period. You can't expose its setter to a *specific* class. You can, however, limit the accessibility to its setter by using the keywords `Friend`, `Private`, or `Protected`:

- `Friend Set` --> will make the setter accessible (make the property writable) inside the current project and read-only outside the project.
- `Private Set` --> will make the setter accessible from the child classes.
- `Protected Set` --> will make the setter accessible from the derived classes.

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4662180/4934172) to get a better idea on how to limit the accessibility of a property setter. *It's about C#, but the concept is the same*.

Comment: @lucasugar please only use the 'edit' link to improve answers/questions, not to reply. If you'd like to address something in an answer, you can either add a comment or edit your question and add the new information. I already took care of that for you.

Comment: Yes, you're right. The `Friend` keyword is what I need. Thank you very much.

Comment: @lucasugar Glad I was able to help. If the answer solved your problem, you might consider [accepting it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). If there's still something not clear, please let me know.